# How to handle known errors that have no reason to be thrown

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I am very aware of the problems with using `uncaughtException` in my code.  I am also aware that the `domains` module is being deprecated so I do not want to use that.   My question is what to do when I encounter an error that should not happen.  For instance, if using mongo db and mongoose the following code example is give:

```
var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('meow');
  }
});
```

Here there is, what I assume is an inexplicable error.  It is caught, but only uses console.log to log the error.  Clearly more would have to happen to inform the user there is a problem, but I am wondering what should happen to the rest of the application.

Should it shutdown? Should something else happen? I have a good number of cases where I can catch errors like this, but if they happen they represent some very weird situation where something like the database has failed, or something else from another library has failed for no explicable reason and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to return a json to your app showing the results of operation. Example:

```
if(err) {
  res.status(500).json({saved: false, errormsg: 'Cannot save to database'});
} else {
  res.json({saved: true, errormsg: null});
}
```

Handle the response in your app and show to the user that some bad think happened.